# Qt creator error during release qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qtcore

I have error when I try qmake my project in release mode. In debug mode everything is ok, but when I change to release - 'magic' starts. I have no clue what is wrong. Before I could several times qmake release version. What am I doing wrong? (below some output - sorry for partly polish information)

```
ASSERT: "fileName.isEmpty() || isAbsolutePath(fileName)" in file Q:\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase\qmake\library\ioutils.cpp, line 61
20:20:45: Proces "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2010_opengl\bin\qmake.exe" zakończył się kodem wyjściowym 1.
```

(translate: 20:20:45: Process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2010_opengl\bin\qmake.exe" finish with return code 1.)

Comment: I have no clue where can I find it - I haven't got "Q:" volume.

Comment: The OP doesn't have that code, it's an internal error from `qmake`.

Comment: Looks like internal error in QMake, try to delete build directory and re-build.

Comment: I've deleted directory and tired to rebuild - still error. But I've create another project with the same name etc, but in diffrent direcotry - now it works o.O There is only one answer - magic.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: surely, the OP does have the code since Qt is open source; everyone has it.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. OP try configuring qt with a non-default prefix like configure.bat--prefix="C:\Qt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite magical. You either used back slashes, etc, a.k.a. wrong input path or were simply facing this already fixed bug in later versions:

[qmake is crashing with "Qwt 6.1 rc3" and Qt 5](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29642)

As you can see, this was fixed in 5.2.0 when wrong path is supplied. Based on your comment that `Q:\` was unknown for you, it could also be the reason for the crash.